# Can a typical shared host serve both Django & RoR simultaneously?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, ruby-on-rails

I'm going to be building two independent applications (one on Django, and one on Rails). I was wondering whether it's reasonable to expect a shared host to be able to do both simultaneously.

(Like, can a standard, nothing-special host run multiple instances of apache which each serve a different platform. Or can apache serve both simultaneously?)

Answer (score 0):

Apache could serve both at once, but the memory demands might lead your host to strongly suggest a VPS.